# How do I pass data to a widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, audio, local, assets, playback

I have a json file containing a list of titles and songNumbers. I made a listview and used onTap and Navigator.push to send det data to a detail page. It works fine to display the data as text, but I want to play songs from local assets. I use audioplayers package and if I hardcode a songname it works, but I want to pass the songname into the play function to play the selected song. My code for det detail page look (a bit simplified and shortened) like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

class SongDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String songNumber;

  final player = AudioCache();

  SongDetail(this.title, this.songNumber);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget titleSection = Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blueGrey[50],
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
            child: IconButton(icon: Icon(
                Icons.play_circle_filled,
                size: 40.0),
                onPressed: () { player.play('1.mp3'); },
              ),
          ),
```

I can use Text(this.title) and Text(this.songNumber) to display the title and songNumber as text. But how to get the data from songNumber into the onPressed function instead of the hardcoded '1.mp3'?

Bear in mind that I am a newbie who maybe has taken a to difficult task, but I like challenges :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
onPressed: () { player.play('$songNumber.mp3'); },
```

Comment: Thank You for answering. Yes I have tried that. Gives error.

Comment: I added songNumber later in the Project when I found that I wanted melody to the songs. No I tried to change the song name in assets folder to the same as the title, and used `player.play('$title.mp3')` and everything works perfectly fine! So I have to figure out what is wrong with songNumber in the project.Think I will try to rewrite the whole code again. But thank you guys for given me help and put me in the right direction. And I know I have to study more of the theory...